# Connect Thread and access public variables

Tags: multithreading, qt

I have created a thread in the `main()-function`.
The thread is emitting a signal at one point.
I want the signal to invoke a slot in an object created by the `QMainWindow class` `PPI w;` which is than trying to access the public object `videoSocket`. My thread is working perfectly but as far as I know it is not possible to connect a signal to a slot in the `main()-function`.  But when I am trying to create the thread in the `QMainWindow Class` but programm crashs.

This code works (axcept for the connect):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    PPI w;
    w.show();

    VideoUDPSocketThread videoUDPSocketThread;
    videoUDPSocketThread.start();

    //connect(&videoUDPSocketThread, SIGNAL(videoRead(int)), &w, SLOT(onVideoRead(int)), Qt::QueuedConnection);

    return a.exec();
}
```

This code will cause my program to crash:

```
PPI::PPI(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
: QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    ppiScene = new PPIScene(this);
    ppiScene->setSceneRect(0,0,SCENEWIDTH,SCENEHEIGHT);
    ui.gVPPI->setScene(ppiScene);

    videoImage = new QImage();
    videoPixmap = ppiScene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*videoImage));


    VideoUDPSocketThread videoUDPSocketThread;
    //videoUDPSocketThread.start(); <--CRASH

    connect(&videoUDPSocketThread.videoSocket, SIGNAL(videoRead(int)), this, SLOT(onVideoRead(int)));
}
```

VideoUDPSocketThread.h

```
#ifndef VIDEOUDPSOCKETTHREAD_H
#define VIDEOUDPSOCKETTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include "videoudpsocket.h"

class VideoUDPSocketThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    //VideoUDPSocketThread(QObject *parent);
    VideoUDPSocketThread();
    ~VideoUDPSocketThread();
    VideoUDPSocket videoSocket;

private:

protected:
    void run();
};

#endif // VIDEOUDPSOCKETTHREAD_H
```

VideoUDPSocketThread.cpp

```
#include "videoudpsocketthread.h"

/*VideoUDPSocketThread::VideoUDPSocketThread(QObject *parent)
    : QThread(parent)
{

}*/

VideoUDPSocketThread::VideoUDPSocketThread()
{

}

VideoUDPSocketThread::~VideoUDPSocketThread()
{

}

void VideoUDPSocketThread::run()
{
    VideoUDPSocket videoSocket;
    exec();
}
```

> QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
>
> Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) bei 0x5d9d5a29 in ppi.exe: 0xC0000005: Zugriffsverletzung beim Lesen an Position 0x00000074.
>
> Unbehandelte Ausnahme bei 0x5d9d5a29 in ppi.exe: 0xC0000005: Zugriffsverletzung beim Lesen an Position 0x00000074.

(My try to translate this error into English:)

> QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
>
> An exception (first chance) occured at 0x5d9d5a29 in ppi.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation while reading at position 0x00000074.
>
> Untreated exception at 0x5d9d5a29 in ppi.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation while reading at position 0x00000074.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a Thread on the stack in PPI's constructor. This means it will be destroyed the second you function returns. I think you want something like this:

```
PPI::PPI(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
: QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    ppiScene = new PPIScene(this);
    ppiScene->setSceneRect(0,0,SCENEWIDTH,SCENEHEIGHT);
    ui.gVPPI->setScene(ppiScene);

    videoImage = new QImage();
    videoPixmap = ppiScene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*videoImage));


    VideoUDPSocketThread * videoUDPSocketThread = new VideoUDPSocketThread();

    // connect BEFORE starting to ensure thread safety (this is very important)
    // connect the finished signal to the deleteLater slot to make sure your memory doesn't leak
    // also use the new connection syntax, compiler warnings are nice
    connect( &videoUDPSocketThread->videoSocket, &VideoUDPSocket::videoRead, this, &PPI::onVideoRead );
    connect( videeoUDPSocketThread, &QThread::finished, videeoUDPSocketThread, &QObject::deleteLater ); 

    // now you can start the tread
    videeoUDPSocketThread->start();
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you this helped me alot! Besides of a few error (i edited your code and comment your part) in your code, the second connect-statement does not work. The compiler tells me, I cannot access the protected members of QThread (but when i look at the definitions they seem to be public?). Well okay i do not think i will have problems with memory, since the thread is running through the whole lifetime and the program (and even until the computer is resetted), but I sure would love to know how to make it correct, for programming style and of course if I need that at another point in any program.

Comment: That's weird, signals are always public and deleteLater is also a public slot. Are you sure the error does not come from somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I am but I figured out the problem, the connect statements have to look like this: `connect( videoUDPSocketThread->videoSocket, SIGNAL(videoRead(int)), this, SLOT(onVideoRead(int)));`
    `connect( videoUDPSocketThread, SIGNAL(&QThread::finished), videoUDPSocketThread, SLOT(&QObject::deleteLater)); `

Comment: connect( videoUDPSocketThread, SIGNAL(&QThread::finished), videoUDPSocketThread, SLOT(&QObject::deleteLater)); Does not look valid. But because you use the old syntax it probably doesn't give any compiler warnings.
What exact errors do you get from the compiler if you use my original connects?